# TextInput not appearing

Tags: react-native, textinput

I'm trying to learn React-Native and while it's going pretty smoothly so far, I'm having this weird issue with TextInput.

My page should be rendering both an input field and a switch, but it only shows a switch. It was working earlier, but coming back after editing some other components it is not longer rendering, or at least does not appear to be.

Below is all the code for the component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Switch
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

export default class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textVal: "",
      switchVal: false
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Input`,
  });

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("submitted");
  }

  onSwitchChange(value) {
    this.setState({
      switchVal: value
    });
  }


  render() {
    console.log("hello");
    return(
      <View>
          <TextInput
          style={styles.t2}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({textVal: text})}
          placeholder="Hi"
          value={this.state.textVal}
          onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmit}
          />
          <Text style={styles.t1}>
            {this.state.textVal}
          </Text>
          <Switch
            value={this.state.switchVal}
            onValueChange={(value) => this.onSwitchChange(value)}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  t1: {
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 200,
  },
  t2: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 200
  }
});
```

Comment: Code is working fine at my end.

Comment: Works fine for me as well.